# How to make a USB bootable if there is a partition table that have to be kept

Tags: partition, dd, live-usb, bootable

How to create a bootable usb if I want to keep the partition tables of my usb?

A simple `dd` on the subpartition (e.g `/dev/sdb1`) is not going to work.

**Example**: I have the partition

```
# lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 20.0G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:1    0  4.0G  0 part 
├─sdb2        8:2    0  16.0G  0 part
```

I want to

- have a live OS on `sdb1`
- have data on `sdb2`

Comment: you're going to have to modify the partition table in some way, either to set the boot flag on an existing partition or to create a new partition that has the boot flag set. you won't be able to boot into the usb if none of the partitions are marked as bootable.